# Algorithms for Minimum resource requirements

Tags: algorithm

I have a question for which I have made some solutions, but I am not happy with the scalability. I'm looking for input of some different approaches / algorithms to solving it.

**Problem:**

> Software can run on electronic controllers (ECUs) and requires
>   different resources to run a given feature. It may require a given
>   amount of storage or RAM or a digital or Analog Input or Output for
>   instance. If we have multiple features and multiple controller options
>   we want to find the combination that minimizes the hardware
>   requirements (cost). I'll simplify the resources to letters to
>   simplify the understanding.

**Example 1:**

```
Feature1(A)
ECU1(A,B,C)
```

First a trivial example. Lets assume that a feature requires 1 unit of resource A, and ECU has 1 unit of resources A, B and C available, it is obvious that the feature will fit in the ECU with resources B & C left over.

**Example 2:**

```
Feature2(A,B)
ECU2(A|B,B,C)
```

In this example, Feature 2 requires resources A and B, and the ECU has 3 resources, the first of which can be A or B. In this case, you can again see that the feature will fit in the ECU, but only if check in a certain order. If you assign F(A) to E(A|B), then F(B) to E(B) it works, but if you assign F(B) to E(A|B) then there is no resource left on the ECU for F(A) so it doesn't appear to fit. This would lead one to the observation that we should prefer non-OR'd resources first to avoid such a conflict. 
An example of the above could be a an analog input could also be used as a digital input for instance.

**Example 3**

```
Feature3(A,B,C)
ECU3(A|B|C, B|C, A|C)
```

Now things are a little bit more complicated, but it is still quite obvious to a person that the feature will fit into the ECU.

My problems are simply more scaled up versions of these examples (i.e. multiple features per ECU with more ECUs to choose from.

**Algorithms**

**GA**
My first approach to this was to use a genetic algorithm. For a given set of features i.e. F(A,B,C,D), and a list of currently available ECUs find which single or combination of ECUs fit the requirements.

ECUs would initially be randomly selected and features checked they fitted and added to them. If a feature didn't fit another ECU was added to the architecture. A population of these architectures was created and ranked based on lowest cost of housing all the features. Architectures could then be mated in successive generations with mutations and such to improve fitness.

This approached worked quite well, but tended to get stuck in local minima (not the cheapest option) based on a golden example I had worked by hand.

**Combinatorial / Permutations**
My next approach was to work out all of the possible permutations (the ORs from above) for an ECU to see if the features fit.

If we go back to example 2 and expand the ORs we get 2 permutations;

```
Feature2(A,B)
ECU2(A|B,B,C) = (A,B,C), (B,B,C)
```

From here it is trivial to check that the feature fits in the first permutation, but not the second.

...and for example 3 there are 12 permutations

```
Feature3(A,B,C)
ECU3(A|B|C, B|C, A|C) = (A,B,A), (B,B,A), (C,B,A), (A,C,A), (B,C,A), (C,C,A), (A,B,C), (B,B,C), (C,B,C), (A,C,C), (B,C,C), (C,C,C)
```

Again it is trivial to check that feature 3 fits in at least one of the permutations (3rd, 5th & 7th).

Based on this approach I was also able to get a solution also, but I have ECUs with so many OR'd inputs that I have millions of ECU permutations which drastically increased the run time (minutes). I can live with this, but first wanted to see if there was a better way to skin the cat, apart from Parallelizing this approach.

> So that is the problem...

I have more ideas on how to approach it, but assume that there is a fancy name for such a problem or the name of the algorithm that has been around for 20+ years that I'm not familiar with and I was hoping someone could point me in that direction to either some papers or the names of relevant algorithms.

The obvious remark of simply summing the feature resource requirements and creating a new monolithic ECU is not an option. Lastly, no, this is not in any way associated with any assignment or problem given by a school or university.

Sorry for the long question, but hopefully I've sufficiently described what I am trying to do and this peaks the interest of someone out there.

Sincerely, Paul.

Comment: Did you considered -Constrained Programming- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming to solve your problem?

Comment: Christian, I had not looked at that, thank you for the lead. My current solutions were implemented in Python and I see there are some Constraint packages for python so I'll give one a try.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like individual feature plug can be solved as bipartite matching.

You make bipartite graph:

- left side corresponds to feature requirements
- right side corresponds to ECU subnodes
- edges connect each left and right side vertixes with common letters

Let me explain by example 2:

- Feature2(A,B)
- ECU2(A|B,B,C)

How graph looks:

- 2 left vertexes: L1 (A), L2 (B)
- 3 right vertexes: R1 (A|B), R2 (B), R3 (C)
- 3 edges: L1-R1 (A-A|B), L2-R1 (B-A|B), L2-R2 (B-B)

Then you find maximal matching for unordered bipartite graph. There are few well-known algorithms for it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)

If maximal matching covers every feature vertex,  we can use it to plug feature.

If maximal matching does not cover every feature vertex, we are short of resources.

Unfortunately, this approach works like greedy algorithms. It does not know of upcoming features and does not tweak solution to fit more features later. Partially optimization for simple cases can work like you described in question, but in general it's dead end - only algorithm that accounts for every feature in whole feature set can make overall effective solution.

You can try to add several features to one ECU simultaneously. If you want to add new feature to given ECU, you can try all already assigned features plus candidate feature. In this case local optimum solution will be found for given feature set (if it's possible to plug them all to one ECU).

Comment: Alexander, thanks for the answer. I like this approach and this it would be quite computationally inexpensive. I understand your comments relative to not considering future features, but you could simply rerun the test with the extra feature is the computation is cheap enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've not enough reputation to comment, so here's what i wanted to propose for your problem:

Like **GA** there are some other *Random Based* approaches too e.g. **Bayesian Apporaoch** , **Decision Tree** etc.

In my opinion *Decision Tree* will suit your problem as it, against some input dataset/attributes, shows a path to each class(in your case ECUs) that helps to select right class/ECU. Train your system with some sample data sets so that it can decide right ECU for your actual data set/Features.

Check [Decision Trees - Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) for more information. Hope it helps!

Comment: Muhammad, thanks for the idea. I'll have to think about this approach a bit more. My initial thought wouldn't have been that this approach mapped to this problem because there isn't correlation between resource requirements of different features and whether they would fit in an ECU. Knowing a feature for instance will fit in an ECU with 89% confidence is different to knowing it will fit. If I am misunderstanding, please correct me.